# Ruby Twitter how to authorize user?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter

I have an app which must to tweet in user's page.

Using gem [Twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)

I have an action which must create all stuff.

```
def call
  client = set_client

  client.token

  client.update!("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
end
```

This method create client for using API

```
def set_client
  Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = "****"
    config.consumer_secret     = "****"
    config.access_token        = "****"
    config.access_token_secret = "****"
  end
end
```

If I think correct I need to get user's access_token and authorize him with permissions.
But in app's setting I can get token for my page only.

How I can realize the feature, when I'm getting user's access_token and access_token_secret?

Answer (score 3):

To get an access token and secret for a user, you need to complete Twitter's 3-legged authorization.

Gem [omniauth-twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter) makes this process easy, and it is even explained in a nice railscasts tutorial

Assuming you have omniauth configured and a UsersController with:

```
def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
end
```

Then in the User model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice("provider", "uid")).first || create_from_omniauth(auth)
end

def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["nickname"]
    user.access_token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
    user.access_token_secret = auth["credentials"]["secret"]
  end
end

def set_client
  Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = "****"
    config.consumer_secret     = "****"
    config.access_token        = access_token
    config.access_token_secret = access_token_secret
  end
end
```

More info: [3-legged authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged) and [railscasts tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised)

Comment: Links to [3-legged authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged) and [railscasts tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised). Sorry for not posting links in the answer, I just joined the site and it wouldn't let me add more than one.